# If notification group is blocked but channel is enabled, will the notification get displayed?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

Android P gives capability to disable a notification group. If this group is disabled by the user, will notifications belonging to a channel in the group be displayed? (assuming the channel is still enabled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, notifications belonging to that channel will not be displayed. A notification channel will be blocked if the channel group it belongs to is blocked. From [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#getImportance()) for `NotificationChannel.getImportance()`:

> ..notifications posted to this channel will not be shown to the user
>   if the parent NotificationChannelGroup or app is blocked.